# Why won't my dataframe column in pandas convert to datetime dtype?

Tags: pandas, datetime, python-3.7

I want to change my dataframe column to datetime, but whenever I run the code it doesn't change the `dtype` from `object` to `datetime64[ns]`

```
df['expiration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['expiration'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['expiration']
```

this shows

```
57098    2017-02-01
57248    2017-01-27
57430    2017-01-27
57589    2017-01-25
57590    2017-01-25
57591    2017-01-25
57601    2017-01-27
57602    2017-01-27
57784    2017-01-25
57785    2017-01-25
57786    2017-01-25
Name: expiration, Length: 642, dtype: object
```

I expected the `dtype` to be `datetime64[ns]` but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: Works for me. You can also try `df['expiration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['expiration'], errors='coerce')`.

Comment: that didn't seem to work for me, it's still showing up as `dtype: object`

Comment: Maybe your original data have some nan values.

Comment: it doesn't look like that's the case either, since if it had nan values then the rest of my code would break somewhere because of it

Comment: Try something as simple as `pd.to_datetime(df['expiration'])` and tell us the resulting `dtype`.

Comment: I just did that and it still output `dtype: object`

Comment: I see 2 scenarios here: either `pd.to_datetime` does not work for some reason or you have some irregularities in your data. For former, I would try `pd.to_datetime` on small subset that could be visually checked for format consistency. For latter, I would further investigate your `expiration` column.

Comment: I believe that `pd.to_datetime` is not working because I tried it with a smaller set of dates and it still outputs `dtype: object` . Also I went through all of the data I was using in my original code and did not find any nan or missing values.

Comment: You may ponder over such a fact: both @QuangHoang and me were able to convert sample data in your question to timestamp (those 11 lines). (i) Can you try converting those lines to timestamp and see if you succeed? (ii) Perhaps a stupid suggestion, but can you add to your question original `object` dtype data you're trying to convert? Just in case, neither `nan` nor `None` could be the source of your problem.

Comment: Okay, now it seems to want to work. Not sure what was going on but now it outputs the entire column with `dtype: datetime64[ns]`. I'm confused as to why I had this problem in the first place, because I just got it to run properly with the code I originally posted as well as with `df['expiration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['expiration'])`

Comment: Thank you both for helping but I'm not sure what the problem was or how it was resolved, since I just wrote the same code that I did when I encountered the problem. However, now the code runs fine and outputs what I want.